# Columns doesnt count right

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

So I got this example:
[image]

The green value should show 01:00:00 but it doesnt. I think the formula I got "ROUND" it somehow (I got the code online). And I need this code so the value can exceed 24 hours. I've tried to remova "ROUND" in the code but only getting syntax errors.

```
IF(INT(Minuter/60)<10;"0"&INT(Minuter/60);INT(Minuter/60))&":"&IF(ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0)<10;"0"&ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0);ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0))&":"&TEXT([Ärende påbörjat]-[Ärende inkommet];"ss"))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `HOUR/MINUTE` to calculate the hours/minutes instead of `ROUND`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#calculate-the-difference-between-two-times

Sample test demo:

```
=IF(HOUR([DateB]-[DateA])>0,"0"&HOUR([DateB]-[DateA])&":"&CONCATENATE(REPT("0",2-LEN(MINUTE([DateB]-[DateA]))),MINUTE([DateB]-[DateA]))&":00","00:"&MINUTE([DateB]-[DateA])&":00")
```

[image]